# Asp.net / JavaScript Can't remove entry from table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to remove my entry to my table but when I press the remove button nothing happends, I know it goes into the remove method as it hits my Alert I did set there.

This is my Script to open a dialog:

```
    function OpenDialog2(id, projectId, startDate, endDate, pct) {
    ClearDialog();
    $('#projectList').val(projectId);
    $('#startDate').val(startDate);
    $('#endDate').val(endDate);
    $('#pct').val(pct);
    $('#sId').text(id);
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
}
```

This is my method trying to remove it:

```
                'Ta bort': function () {
                alert("Ta bort");
                var sid = $('#sId').text();
                if (sid !== "") {
                    locstring = "@Url.Action("Index")/Delete/" + sid;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: locstring,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $('#dialog').dialog('close');
                            reloadTable();
                        }
                    });

                }
```

This is my Partial View:

```
        @foreach (var project in ViewData["times"] as List<ConsultantProjectTime>)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="javascript:OpenDialog2('@project.ID','@project.FK_ProjectID','@project.StartDate.ToShortDateString()','@project.EndDate.ToShortDateString()','@project.Pct');">
                    @project.Project.ProjectName
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>@(project.StartDate.ToShortDateString() + " - " + project.EndDate.ToShortDateString())</td>
            <td>@(project.Pct)%</td>
            <td>
                @if (project.Project.StartDate.HasValue && project.Project.EndDate.HasValue)
                {
                    @(project.Project.StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString() + " - " + project.Project.EndDate.Value.ToShortDateString())
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Comment: about the space in 'Ta bort': function () {  i don't think is acceptable

Comment: @IlyasMimouni I noticed what the error is I think, when I create these posts they don't get an ID. SO trying to figure out why they don't.

Comment: What does **reloadTable()** do? Does it only repopulates model or renders view as well?

Comment: alert(data); in the success call back. do you get anything?

Comment: @Rajesh reloadTable Just reloads the table.

Comment: So is there a call/function that updates the model itself? Ideally, you should send delete request to server and after delete repopulate data. This can be done in one call, but will assure integrity of data displayed. Just check if you are repopulating the data or not?

Comment: The problem where in my view.. I had to include     <span id="sId" style="display: none;"></span>